# Extracting vendor libraries from factor-bundle

Tags: npm, browserify-shim, factor-bundle

I am creating a semi-automatic build pipeline for my application using npm, Gulp, and browserify. This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

- Have page specific files which I can include via script tags (i.e. `page1.js`, `page2.js`, ...)
- Factor out my custom code that is shared inbetween the page specific scripts as `common.js`.
- Extract vendor libraries (i.e. bootstrap, jquery) installed via npm into `vendor.js`.

I'm having trouble combining browserify and browserify-shim for my application. In my webpage, I include `vendor.js`, `common.js`, and `page1.js`. When I try to load the page and my script is trying to `require('bootstrap')`, an exception is thrown here:

```
// Part of bootstrap.js
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery')
}
```

I expect to have to tell browserify-shim that bootstrap depends on jquery, that it expects jquery's export to be bound to the jQuery variable. I attempted to do this in my package.json.

I'm having trouble pinpointing exactly what is going wrong. I've tried various permutations of values to go into bootstrap's shim (`jquery:jQuery`, `jquery:$`, `jquery`) to no avail. I've also tried including and omitting various values in the `browser` path. I also tried building the vendor bundle via the command line using: `./node_modules/.bin/browserify -r jquery -r bootstrap > vendor.js`, but the same error comes up on the browser. A lot of questions have been asked about browserify-shim and factor-bundle, but none of them address anyone trying to combine the two.

I have created a repository that demonstrates the issue here. Steps to install and reproduce are in the README. https://github.com/linkleonard/browserify-shim-factor-bundle